# How to Loop through BOLD lines over Richtextbox?

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox, vb.net-2010, rtf

Richtextbox text is :

Tried code :

```
for I as integer=0 to richtextboxBold.lines.length-1

   If islineBold(richtextboxBold.liines(I)) then 

      richtextboxOutput.AppendText("Line "& I &" is Bold")
   Else

      richtextboxOutput.AppendText("Line "& I &" is Not Bold")

   End If

Next

Function islineBold(byval str as string) as Boolean

End Function
```

Output Required :

> Line 1 is Bold
>   Line 2 is Not Bold

Comment: On which language exactly? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: I believe regex would the simplest? unless the RichTextBox has a property/function that returns it (which I doubt)

Comment: @johan want to do some operations over only bold lines in rich text box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Dim sLine As String        
Dim iCont As Integer

For (i As Integer = 0 To rt.Lines.Lenght - 1)
    sLine = rt.Lines(i)
    rt.Select(iCont, sLine.Length - 1)

    If rt.SelectionFont.Bold Then
        richtextboxOutput.AppendText("Line "& i + 1 &" is Bold")
    Else
        richtextboxOutput.AppendText("Line "& i + 1 &" is Not Bold")
    End If

    iCont += sLine.Length
Loop
```

Where `rt` is the `RichTextBox`. This will check if the whole line is bold.

You can't test if something is bold passing only a string to the function, as the only option then is to find the text into the RichTextBox and could be repeated. If you want to do a function you could do something like this:

```
Function IsBoldText(rt As RichTextBox, start As Integer, length As Integer)
    rt.Select(start, length)
    Return rt.SelectionFont.Bold
End Function
```